# Pattern recognition algorithms

Tags: algorithm, pattern-recognition

In the past I had to develop a program which acted as a rule evaluator. You had an antecedent and some consecuents (actions) so if the antecedent evaled to true the actions where performed.

At that time I used a modified version of the [RETE algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) (there are three versions of RETE only the first being public) for the antecedent pattern matching. We're talking about a big system here with million of operations per rule and some operators "repeated" in several rules.

It's possible I'll have to implement it all over again in other language and, even though I'm experienced in RETE, does anyone know of other pattern matching algorithms? Any suggestions or should I keep using RETE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TREAT algorithm is similar to RETE, but doesn't record partial matches. As a result, it may use less memory than RETE in certain situations. Also, if you modify a significant number of the known facts, then TREAT can be much faster because you don't have to spend time on retractions.

There's also [RETE*](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Publications/Papers/2000091.pdf) which balances between RETE and TREAT by saving some join node state depending on how much memory you want to use. So you still save some assertion time, but also get memory and retraction time savings depending on how you tune your system.

You may also want to check out [LEAPS](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/ftp/pub/predator/tr-94-28.pdf), which uses a lazy evaluation scheme and incorporates elements of both RETE and TREAT.

I only have personal experience with RETE, but it seems like RETE* or LEAPS are the better, more flexible choices.

Comment: LEAPS link: ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/predator/tr-94-28.pdf

Comment: these are all dead links. Fortunately, they've been preserved in the archive: Rete* (https://web.archive.org/web/20130921054452/http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Publications/Papers/2000091.pdf) and LEAPS (https://web.archive.org/web/20080906184828/http://www.cs.utexas.edu/ftp/pub/predator/tr-94-28.pdf)